# vim colorscheme: changing only the cursor properties

Tags: vim

I am using colorscheme desert256.
It is quite nice except for an annoying detail:
I cannot really tell where the cursor is sometimes.

How can I change just the cursor style, (say make it red)?

Thanks

Comment: You should ask this on SuperUser. I think they will be able to help you out more.

Answer (score 2):

Got most of this from the vim wiki... These settings will allow you to make changes. Experiment with them in your .vimrc...

Line 1 defines the color highlighting used for n-v-c modes (set in line 3), and line 2 defines a different color for insert mode (set in line 4). Line 5 disables blinking (blinkon value 0) for n-v-c modes, and line 6 increases the default blink rate for insert mode. Line 4 also sets the cursor shape to a 100% sized vertical bar for insert mode (the default is ver25, a 25% vertical bar).

```
highlight Cursor guifg=white guibg=black
highlight iCursor guifg=white guibg=steelblue
set guicursor=n-v-c:block-Cursor
set guicursor+=i:ver100-iCursor
set guicursor+=n-v-c:blinkon0
set guicursor+=i:blinkwait10
```